# Confusion about the estimated phase angle in SRF-PLL

Tags: power-electronics, control, pll, srf

I am working on a simple PLL Simulink model as a proof of concept:

[image: Simulink Model]

I have two problems that are causing confusion for me at the moment:

1. What should the estimated phase angle look like?  Mine is like this. I feel that something is not correct because all the references I saw the plot is different, it starts from 0 and continues as a sawtooth signal. Mine here does something weird in the beginning. Is that a tuning issue in the PI controller?

[image: Estimated phase angle]

2. What should How the Vd component of the voltage look like?
   Mine is stabilizing at a negative value. Is that correct?

Edit:

The expected estimation as found in the literature is something like this:

[image: Expected estimation]

Comment: It's your design so if it doesn't look right to you then what is the criteria by which you make that decision (nobody reading this will know that of course).

Comment: I edited the question and added a picture of what seems to be the normal response to expect for such SRF-PLL systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "weird thing at the beginning" is expected. That's the startup transient, when the state of the phase detector has to catch up with the relative phase of the inputs.

SPICE simulators usually let you start a circuit from a DC operating point solution that may suppress such transients. But that's not realistic, just convenient when simulating "steady state" behavior. For a "whole picture", the SPICE model should use voltage sources that ramp up at a certain rate on startup - then the startup transients will be at least somewhat representative of what a real circuit might do, for real circuits never experience "infinitely fast" power-up, as it's not physically realizable. The slew rate of power supply voltages is finite.

> the plot is different, it starts from 0

Remember that the plots you see in books are idealized. Startup transients are quite varied and there's no "one size fits all" representation for them. Nevertheless, EE books, especially targeting beginners, should be covering this and striving to have graphs that approximate the real world a bit better :)

No physical phase detector has its output start at zero on power up, unless it's very carefully designed to act that way. For a vast majority of circuits, such ideal behavior is unnecessary. And, conversely, the remainder of the circuit should not depend on such unrealistically ideal behavior.

In some cases, the startup transient needs more care, say in low circuits that switch their supply on-and-off frequently to conserve power.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this. This was my confusion because I am aware that should be some transient response due to the PI regulator I am using. But that didn't appear in much of the literature I am currently exploring. But how do these plots (which are sometimes in conference papers) idealize results?

Comment: *But how do these plots (which are sometimes in conference papers) idealize results?*  They do so by showing what happens once the system is running, and by ignoring what happens when it gets powered up. The startup transient may well be irrelevant to the operation and implementation-specific. Basically, everyone who deals in this field knows about such idealizations. What you've experienced is a common tripping point for novices. And besides: once you start writing your own papers, you'll learn lots about idealizations quickly. Papers need focus, and some details just detract.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful

Comment: *I am aware that [there] should be some transient response due to the PI regulator I am using* Phase detectors don't update their output infinitely quickly. Signal sources don't get working immediately on power up. Etc. Even without a PI regulator, you'll have a startup transient. The PI regulator may well exacerbate it as the integrator gets to the steady state. Ultra high accuracy PLL circuits used in laboratory time references sometimes need hours or days to fully stabilize. Their startup "transient" effectively may last a week or a month!